# VBA lookup code

Tags: vba, excel, lookup

I have been using the following formula in excel:

`=LOOKUP(2,1/((Sheet1!$G:$G=$C7)*(Sheet1!$H:$H=I$6)),Sheet1!$F:$F)`

This ultimately tells me that, look in column `A` and match cell `B1`, and look in column `C` and match cell `D1`, then return the date in column `Z`.

This works fine, but after 4000 rows and 100 columns wide, it take 20min to save the document.

How can I put this code - or something similar - into VBA. Excel formulas are not a problem, but I'm a severe newbie with VBA. This code will be on 1 sheet in 1 workbook, but look up data is on another workbook.

Column `A` and cell `B1` will be text, column `C` and cell `D1` will be numbers, column `Z` are dates.

Appreciate any and all help on this.

Comment: can you copy-paste some formula to values? that will probably lower the saving time

Answer (score 0):

How about an Index/Match array formula? It would be something like

```
{=INDEX($Z:$Z,MATCH(1,($A:$A=$B$1)*($C:$C=$D$1),0))}
```

This will return the corresponding value in column Z where the value in column A matches B1 and the value in column C matches D1.

This is an array formula and must be committed with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.